# How to call Object from one class other

Tags: java, android

In my Android project there is a MainActivity.java

```
MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

       BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    }
  }
```

How to use mBluetoothAdapter object in the below class

```
public class AvailableDevices extends ListFragment {

     // How to call mBluetoothAdapter here
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: `BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass it as a parameter to the constructor of the class

```
public class AvailableDevices extends ListFragment {
   private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
   public AvailableDevices(BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter) {
       this.bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothAdapter;
   }
}
```

or declare it as a static public data member

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    public static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    ..
 }
```

and then in the other class use MainActivity.mBluetoothAdapter

or make the AvailableDevices an inner class and declare the adapter as a data member:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    ..
    class AvailableDevices extends ListFragment {
         //can use mBluetoothAdapter
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an ugly and completely unnecessary dependency on MainActivity. If using static or singleton Objects, I would as the very least keep it in a separate class. Personally I use Dagger to do dependency injection but may be overkill in many instances I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `BluetoothManager bluetoothManager` at class level ( before onCreate() method ) and other class should be inner class

Comment: if I declare as a class member how to use in other class

Comment: other class should be inner class. Or you can manage with global variable/pakage

Answer (score 1):

```
There are two ways known to me-

Using Static variable:

MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
public static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

       BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    }
  }

public class AvailableDevices extends ListFragment {

     // How to call mBluetoothAdapter here
    use in this class as MainActivity.mBluetoothAdapter

  }


2.Passing mBluetoothAdapter to the constructor of the second class.

MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

       BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    }
  }

public class AvailableDevices extends ListFragment {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter=null;
AvailableDevices(BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter){
     this.mBluetoothAdapter=mBluetoothAdapter;


  }
```